# Save email address to accounts app iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, single-sign-on, user-accounts

I have two apps (eg: App1 and App2) which requires login with an account. What I need to achieve is when an user log-in successfully into the App1, the email address should get saved to the default Accounts app of the device. Then when the user opens up the App2, the email address saved from App1 should show up as a recommendation for the user if he need to use the same account to sign in to App2 as well. Just like some apps do if you click on sign in with Google or Facebook.

Since I am new to iOS, I need to ask if this is possible to achieve in iOS and if yes what procedure should I follow.

**EDIT**

I tried implementing KeyChain for this. Something like below :-

```
void StoreKeysInKeychain (string key, string value) {

        var s = new SecRecord (SecKind.GenericPassword) {
            ValueData = NSData.FromString (value),
            Generic = NSData.FromString (key)
        };
        var err = SecKeyChain.Add (s);
    } 


void GetRecordsFromKeychain (string key)
    {
        SecStatusCode res;
        var rec = new SecRecord (SecKind.GenericPassword) {
            Generic = NSData.FromString (key)
        };
        var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord (rec, out res);
        if (match != null) {
            // nsdata object :  match.ValueData;
        }


    }
```

This way when I login to the App1 with an email address it gets saved and when I open the App2 I get that email address. This works fine. But now the issue is that if I logout from App1  and login with another email address. That account is not visible in App2. How can I get a list of all the email address?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is about share data between  `apps`, check the apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipasteboard

Comment: You can use the keychain to store details. Share them across the apps. It was implemented in google apps.

Comment: @Arasuvel Do you have an example I could refer?

Comment: @helloworld : Please check lazyking answer helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41032789/3515033

Comment: @Arasuvel please check my Edit

Answer (score 2):

you need to use app Group to share information among app, Enable app Group from build settings in both app and certificate , assign same group to them , and put information for each other on a suite of NSuserdefault .

Xamarin documentation for app group is here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/working-with/app-groups/

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can set up a ParseServer that user account management for both apps